# How to easily access Windows file server paths on a Mac?

Tags: automator, smb, unc

I am trying to easily convert Windows server paths (UNC) into Mac server paths (SMB). Currently I paste the link to a text editor and "find and replace" every character to an SMB format.

I think the best option here is to run a mac automator script (looks like winshortcutter used to be the free solution, but now it's a subscription service...)

I've been trying to follow the below links but when I run it, nothing happens.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5630586?answerId=31498385022#31498385022
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46129/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-mac-style-file-locations
- http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040322155331393 (<--
  this is the most recent one I tried)

I am running Big Sur and I'm guessing that the solutions in the links above are outdated?

- I can't make AppleScript run as a "Service" or "Quick Action". It doesn't show up.
- When I try to run it as an application, I can tell it is running but nothing happens.
- I'm not sure how to debug it to see where the issue is.